# UEFI variable size

Tags: firmware, uefi, motherboard

I am storing persistent variables with UEFI. I am noticing weird behavior. Before I set the variable, I query `MaximumVariableSize` (with `QueryVariableInfo`) and I receive back a number, such as 65,000. I then write 19 bytes to a variable (and I use a variable name of less than 100 characters, so the name is 200 UTF-16 bytes). When I query the maximum variable size again, I receive back 64,000.

Presumably, 65,000 and 64,000 are in units of **bytes**. Why would writing a variable that consumes a total of 19 + 200 = 219 bytes reduce the free space by 1,000 bytes? Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior? Is this a case of bad fragmentation in the NVRAM? I couldn't immediately find anything about this in the UEFI spec, though to be fair the spec doesn't define the implementation.

**Update:** I've noticed that when I *overwrite* a UEFI variable with content of similar length, `RemainingVariableStorageSize` decreases, even though I haven't increased the total amount of content I am storing in UEFI. I don't know the properties of the NVRAM that backs the firmware. Is it possible that you can only write to each region of NVRAM once per power cycle, which is why it appears the free space is decreasing?

Comment: There is a pretty good description of a possible implementation in https://firmware.intel.com/sites/default/files/resources/A_Tour_Beyond_BIOS_Implementing_UEFI_Authenticated_Variables_in_SMM_with_EDKII.pdf - from the "Variable Reclaim" section onwards.

Comment: @unixsmurf Thanks for the pointer! Will take a look when I wake up tomorrow.

Comment: @unixsmurf Yes, this appears to be what's going on. If you write an answer below, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll just write the answer myself.

Comment: (I could have sworn I commented on this, but if I did, someone deleted the comment and I didn't receive notification.) Thank you for asking, but I'm feeling lazy, so please go ahead and write an answer yourself.

Comment: @unixsmurf Sure, I'll write it. Do you know if it's possible to trigger a reclaim without rebooting the machine? The white paper says this is not supported because it is time consuming, but that doesn't mean it's impossible. I don't immediately see anything about this in the UEFI spec.

Comment: @JackHumphries. The UEFI specification is silent on reclaiming non-volatile variable storage.